# Alinhar divs lado a lado e centralizar

Tags: html, css

estou tentando deixar uma pagina HTML com algumas divs alinhadas lado a lado e centralizadas na página. Tenho o seguinte html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box-texto-1" class="box-texto">Lorem ipsum velit leo risus ultrices pellentesque vehicula etiam ante
        malesuada nec</div>
    <div id="box-1" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="box-2" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="box-3" class="box">3</div>
    <div id="box-texto-2" class="box-texto">Lorem ipsum velit leo risus ultrices pellentesque vehicula etiam ante
        malesuada nec</div>
</div>
```

As divs com `class="box"` devem ficar lado a lodo e centralizadas, já as divs com `classe="box-texto"` não devem ficar centralizadas. A ideia é fazer funcionar apenas com CSS sem criar novas tags.

Tentei usar `foat: left`, ele alinhou lado a lado, mas não consegui centralizar. Tive outras tentativar com `display` mas também sem sucesso.

No link abaixo tem um exemplo onde estava trabalhando:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-m2ngja?file=style.css

Conto com a ajuda de todos!

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

#box-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#box-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#box-3 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="box-texto-1" class="box-texto">Lorem ipsum velit leo risus ultrices pellentesque vehicula etiam ante
        malesuada nec</div>
    <div id="box-1" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="box-2" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="box-3" class="box">3</div>
    <div id="box-texto-2" class="box-texto">Lorem ipsum velit leo risus ultrices pellentesque vehicula etiam ante
        malesuada nec</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ja tentou usar o conceito do bootstrap usando rows e cols ?

Comment: Olá, não tentei isso ainda pois estou tentando fazer com css puro. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seque o modelo, basta colocar `display:inline-block` nas div.box, e `text-alingn:center` no *container*, para as `divs` com texto tb não ficarem centralizada vc declara elas como `text-align:left`.

Repare que eu não adicionai nada no `HTML`, nem tag, nem classe, fiz tudo como `CSS` mantendo o `HTML` que vc apresentou.

*Deixei comentado um comment para vc saber os estilos que eu adicionei*

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
  }
  #box-1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
  #box-2 {
    background-color: green;
  }
  #box-3 {
    background-color: pink;
  }

/* etilos que adicionei */
  #container {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box-texto {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .box {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="box-texto-1" class="box-texto">Lorem ipsum velit leo risus ultrices pellentesque vehicula etiam ante
        malesuada nec</div>
    <div id="box-1" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="box-2" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="box-3" class="box">3</div>
    <div id="box-texto-2" class="box-texto">Lorem ipsum velit leo risus ultrices pellentesque vehicula etiam ante
        malesuada nec</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @Everton dmr jovem! Abs